# Python Unnamed Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, validation

I am having a Dataframe which has unnamed column after the concatenation of various csv file. How can I remove it?

**Code -**

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('amex-listing.xlsx')
exchanges = xls.sheet_names
pd.options.display.width = 10000
final_file = 'listing.xlsx'
listings = []
for exchange in exchanges:
    listing = pd.read_excel('amex-listing.xlsx',sheet_name=exchange, na_values='NaN', index_col=False)
    listing['exchange'] = exchange
    sup_df = pd.DataFrame()
    sup_df = listing.append(sup_df)
    listings.append(sup_df)

listings = pd.concat(listings)
listings = listings.reset_index(drop=True)
print(listings)
```

**Excel data -**

[image]

**Data frame -**

[image]

What should be the best approach to remove the unnamed Dataframe? Also, how can I name this Dataframe if possible?

Comment: I think you changed from talking about an unnamed column that needed removing to an unnamed dataframe that needed removing/renaming... please clarify whether it's the column or the dataframe with which you are having an issue

Comment: That's the index. When writing the excel file, pass `index=False` to `to_excel`

Comment: `pd.to_excel(...., index=False)` if I've misunderstood let me know and i'll flag to re-open.

Comment: @R_Dax Its the column. After using concat() function I am getting index unnmaed column with it in the Dataframe. What is the best approach to remove that column. I tried .drop() but it needs name which is not there due to its generation along with other columns while concatenation.

Comment: Thanks @ifly6. I was able to remove that index. Lol, I was using .drop() xD